# Async Download, how with libcurl or something else?

Tags: c++, c, asynchronous, pthreads, libcurl

after reading the forum, I can't find an answer, so I will try to be clear and be understand.

I try libcurl, but I'm not sure to be able to do that I want (or don't succeed at least).
I use a game engine (cocos2d-x for iPhone and Android) and I need to make a async download to keep the game loop running during the download.

I try to use pthread, but I got many bugs like realloc of non alloc memory or errors on other object I use to get json files.

Do you have an example how to do that ? Or an ohter library ?

I understand the logic of threads, but if you have something simple as ASIHttpRequest on iPhone, it would be nice. Some int and startRequest that finish in a callback where I can do as I want.

Anyway, sorry for my english and thanks in advance.
Damien

Comment: Maybe I don't use libcurl as it does. I try to use this [sample](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html) and just change the function "pull_one_url" to use the [sample](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html). For the moment I'm stack and the function "WriteMemoryCallback" of the second sample on the line : `mem->memory = realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

http://think-async.com/ This should be exactly what you are looking for.

You will have two functions one for starting the connection and another for reading and ending the connection. It would probably help if you wrote a wrapper for these two so you can do HTTP connections in a way that you want, with a single method call.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I try it, but I don't success to use it. I take the non boost version (I guess better for xCode and Eclipse configuration and iPhone / Android device) but I still compile with boost reference, whatever I use the -DBOOST_... settings.